# Script to download manually generated excel file on reference website?

Tags: python, automation

I am specifically looking at the ReferenceUSA website. To download information, one has to manually select all the items, then click download, and then on another page click to generate a CSV file. Is there anyway to automate this kind of process?

Comment: Any code or research so far?

Comment: Look into web scraping, HMTL parsers (`lxml` and `BeatifulSoup`) and possibly the Python module `mechanize`. Or show us your code.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into Beautiful Soup, but don't see how that would help me generate the CSV files, though in theory I should somehow be able to copy the tables of data already on the page (this seems inefficient though).

Comment: @numbersloth Well your question was far too general without any code attempt so I just threw a few things at you that might be relevant in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Selenium, here is an example to open a web page, and click a button.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()  ## now web browser opened
>>> browser.get("https://www.python.org")  ## now python.org web page opened
```

There is a button "GO", its page source code like this:

```
button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="search-button"...
```

Now, click this button

```
>>> browser.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```